# How to concatenate and output unicode text variables in Python

Tags: python, unicode

My title terms might not be correct and may be a reason why I can't find this simple thing from websites.

I have a list of string variables. How do I actually concatenate them and output a real unicode sentence in Python?

```
base = ['280', '281', '282', '283']
end = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f']
unicodes = [u''.join(['\u', j, i]) for j in base for i in end]

for u in unicodes:
    print u
```

I will get only strings like '\u280F' but not real character. But if I do:

```
print u'\u280F'
```

correct symbols shows up, which is: ⠏

And I'm sure there is a more elegant way to get a range of the symbols from u2800 to u283F...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conver the strings to integers (using `int` with `base` 16), the use [`unichr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr) ([`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) if you're using Python 3.x) to convert the number into unicode object.

```
>>> int('280' + 'F', 16)  # => 0x280F, 16: hexadecimal
10255
>>> unichr(int('280' + 'F', 16))  # to unicode object
u'\u280f'
>>> print unichr(int('280' + 'F', 16))
⠏
```

---

```
base = ['280', '281', '282', '283']
end = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f']
unicodes = [unichr(int(j + i, 16)) for j in base for i in end]

for u in unicodes:
    print u
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck with `unicodes` input; you could use `unicode-escape` codecs, to get Unicode (`b'\\u2800'.decode('unicode-escape') == u'\u2800'`):

```
>>> for escaped in unicodes: print escaped.decode('unicode-escape')
...
⠽
⠾
⠿
```

Otherwise, generate range of integers directly:

```
for ordinal in range(0x2800, 0x283f + 1):
    print unichr(ordinal)
```

It produces the same output in this case.